# jQuery scrollTop() not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a chat app, using jquery and bootstrap. I append new chat messages to a div and want to scroll the div so that the most recent message (at the bottom) is always showing. But the scrollTop() function doesn't seem to work. Here is a dummy version of the app: http://www.bootply.com/fE8QRrtNkR
The log-container div is the outer container. Within it, the display-padder div is used to pad the log-container so that when we add messages, they are displayed at the bottom first. Messages are appended to the log div. scrollTop() is called in the appendLog() function.

Comment: Please include the code in the question using a snippet, and not only at an external site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think scrollTop("100%") works. You should replace

```
$('#log').scrollTop("100%");
```

in appendLog function with

```
$('#log-body').scrollTop($("#log").height());
```